# python & pandas- Calculation bewteen rows based on certain values in columns from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame (called df_NoMissing) with thousands of rows, and I need to do calculation and analysis with them.

```
   NoDemande   NoUsager  Sens  IdVehiculeUtilise  Fait  HeureArriveeSurSite   HeureEffective      Periods
0 42196000013  000001    +         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 08:02:07  11/07/2015 08:02:13    Matin
1 42196000013  000001    -         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 08:17:09  11/07/2015 08:17:13    Matin
2 42196000002  000314    +         263Véh          1  11/07/2015 09:37:43  11/07/2015 09:53:37    Matin
3 42196000016  002372    +         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 09:46:42  11/07/2015 10:01:39    Matin
4 42196000015  000466    +         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 09:46:42  11/07/2015 10:01:39    Matin
5 42196000002  000314    -         263Véh          1  11/07/2015 10:25:17  11/07/2015 10:38:11    Matin
6 42196000015  000466    -         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 10:48:51  11/07/2015 10:51:30    Matin
7 42196000016  002372    -         287Véh          1  11/07/2015 11:40:56  11/07/2015 11:41:01    Matin
8 42196000004  002641    +         263Véh          1  11/07/2015 13:39:29  11/07/2015 13:52:50    Soir
9 42196000004  002641    -         263Véh          1  11/07/2015 13:59:56  11/07/2015 14:07:41    Soir
```

What I want to do is to have two rows with the same value in the column `NoDemande`, `NoUsager`, `Periods` but different in column `Sens` do the subtraction between column `HeureArriveeSurSite` and `HeureEffective`. And because the result doesn't correspond to current DataFrame, so the result will be saved in a new DataFrame

---

I tried to separate the DataFrame by identifying `Sens` so I could to the subtraction directly. But it doesn't work at all.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['NoDemande', 'NoUsager', 'Periods', 'DureeTrajet']
df1 = df_NoMissing[(df_NoMissing['Sens'] == '+') & (df_NoMissing['Periods'] == 'Matin')]
df2 = df_NoMissing[(df_NoMissing['Sens'] == '-') & (df_NoMissing['Periods'] == 'Matin')] 

df_new['DureeTrajet'] = df2['HeureArriveeSurSite'].values-df1['HeureEffective'].values
```

This one returned: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1478,) (1479,)`

I also tried the loaded way by telling exactly what I want each time:

```
df1.loc[df1['NoDemande'] == '42196000015','HeureEffective'] - df2.loc[df2['NoDemande'] == '42196000015','HeureArriveeSurSite']
```

But this one came back with:

```
4   NaT
6   NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

So what should I do to get what I want?

---

**EDIT**

The output will look like:

```
  NoDemande   NoUsager   Periods   DureeTrajet
0 42196000013  000001     Matin     00:14:54
1 42196000002  000314     Matin     00:31:40
2 42196000016  002372     Matin     00:39:23
3 42196000015  000466     Matin     00:47:12
4 42196000004  002641     Soir      00:07:06
```

Any help will be really appreciated~

Comment: Hello again!
I think you should try to join (outer join - so all the columns) df1 and df2 and then do the subtraction.

Comment: Yeah~It's me again~ If I join them again, it'll be pointless I split them. Or you mean to join them in the same row?

Comment: @ch36r5s what would an example of output be?

Comment: I mean to join them in the same row - so not append them, but join. For this you should rename all the columns in df2 except of NoDemande, NoUsager and Period. for example, in df1 it will be Sens, in df2 - Sens2. And after join try to subtract the dates as you want.

It can also be that you get some missings, if any of entries do not have a pair with another Sens value.

Comment: I updated with example of output. @NinjaPuppy

Comment: @vlad.rad I'm trying the join. I'm not 100% sure if they are all in pairs (The total output is odd).  What should I do if they're not?

Comment: Those who are not if paits you should just filter out, I think. Because you need just DureeTrajet for those users, who had several sessions, don't you? So, if a user had only one session, you don't need him in the df_new table?

Comment: @ch36r5s for the first one - I get 15:02 instead of 14:54...

Comment: @vlad.rad that's correct. I tried to filter once and I got some improvement. I did it with `duplicate` before, but as a result, I don't know if I fully finished this job

Comment: @NinjaPuppy it's possible. I didn't succeed in doing that so I calculated it myself

Comment: @ch36r5s  I printed an answer so we can discuss everything there. Can you give some update - for have you done and what do you have now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, starting with your DF as provided - let's create an index on the grouping columns and pivot to columns for the `Sens` action:

```
temp = df.set_index(['NoDemande', 'NoUsager', 'Periods']).pivot(columns='Sens')
```

Then - we take the appropriate difference (as according to your code):

```
duration = (temp['HeureArriveeSurSite', '-'] - temp['HeureEffective', '+']).to_frame(name='DureeTrajet').reset_index()
```

That then gives you:

```
     NoDemande  NoUsager Periods  DureeTrajet
0  42196000002       314   Matin     00:31:40
1  42196000004      2641    Soir     00:07:06
2  42196000013         1   Matin     00:14:56
3  42196000015       466   Matin     00:47:12
4  42196000016      2372   Matin     01:39:17
```

Comment: Very nice solution:)

Comment: my DF? Which one? the original one ,the intermediate one or the new one I created for store the result? For the original one, it said: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. For the new one,  it returned: `KeyError: 'Sens'`

Comment: So it returned: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: That means that for a combination of NoDemande, NoUsager and Periods - you have more than one `-` or `+` - eg - you can have either one `-`, one `+` or a group with `+` and `-`, but not a group with `+`, `-` and another `-` - so not sure how you'd want to handle that...

Comment: You might be able to get away with... `temp = df.drop_duplicates(['NoDemande', 'NoUsager', 'Periods', 'Sens']).set_index(['NoDemande', 'NoUsager', 'Periods']).pivot(columns='Sens')`

Comment: That's what I talked about with vlad.rad . Some of the entries are not in pair. Normally, I drop rows with value in `Fait` negative. But I don't know how to test which one have more than two entries with three given conditions.

Comment: @ch36r5s well - you don't need to have pairs... you just can't have more than one of each for the group... otherwise, like you're experiencing you'll get 1-N many joins - while at least this stops you from inadvertently introducing those into your data.

Comment: @ch36r5s can you say a little more about the context? what do you expect at the end? because as Ninka Puppy said, it will be a little more complex if you have more than one of each for the group.

Comment: they represent something in real but no worries about it. with `drop_duplicates` it worked perfectly well. Neat and simple~

Comment: @ch36r5s you can also try running: `df.groupby(['NoDemande', 'NoUsager', 'Periods']).filter(lambda L: len(L) > 2)` to inspect data that you may want to handle later...

Comment: it's about a DARP problem. `+` means pick-up and `-`means delivery, so it has to be in pair. But in fact I have no idea which one is the right one, so let it be...

Comment: Ahh okies... Here's a simple way to check... `df_test = pd.crosstab(index=[df['NoDemande'], df['NoUsager'], df['Periods']], columns=df['Sens'])` then filter out mismatches... `curiousity = df_test[df_test['+'] != df_test['-']]`

Answer (score 1):

So my solution is:

1. to join df1 and df2 (not append them, but join with outer join). For this you should rename all the columns in df2 except of NoDemande, NoUsager and Period. for example, in df1 it will be Sens, in df2 - Sens2. And after join try to subtract the dates as you want.
2. It can also be that you get some missings, if any of entries do not have a pair with another Sens value. hose who are not if paits you should just filter out, I think. Because you need just DureeTrajet for those users, who had several sessions, don't you? So, if a user had only one session, you don't need him in the df_new table?
3. At the end you shoud have only those entries, which have pairs. And for this you can subtract the dates.

**EDIT:**

IF some entries have not just a pair, but two or more pairs, you should then define, which pair has more priority / makes more sense.

Comment: I did it with your answer. But in fact, I have more entries than before. And I don't know why...

Comment: @ch36r5s if you're joining - it's plausible you're getting 1-N matches...

Comment: @ch36r5s I think it is because some entries have not just a pair, but two or more pairs. Can it be so? If so, then you task is more difficult then just subtract one date from another. You should then define, which pair has more priority / makes more sense.

Comment: @vlad.rad yes, it can be. In fact, these coming from raw data needs to be clean. Which I did, but not enough. btw, I might choose the other answer, it's easier...

Comment: Yes, it is easier and nicer, I agree.
But if you liked my answer, can you then give me an upvote?
And post further questions on your task, it is really very interesting.