# python & pandas - How to calculate frequency under conditions in columns in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of data in a DataFrame called `frames`:

```
   NoUsager Sens IdVehiculeUtilise NoConducteur NoAdresse Fait  NoDemande Periods
0   000001   +        287Véh          000087     000079    1   42196000013 Matin 
1   000001   -        287Véh          000087     000079    1   42196000013 Matin 
2   000314   +        263Véh          000077     006470    1   42196000002 Matin 
3   002372   +        287Véh          000087     002932    1   42196000016 Matin 
4   000466   +        287Véh          000087     002932    1   42196000015 Matin 
5   000314   -        263Véh          000077     000456    1   42196000002 Matin 
6   000466   -        287Véh          000087     004900    1   42196000015 Matin 
7   002372   -        287Véh          000087     007072    1   42196000016 Matin 
8   002641   +        263Véh          000077     007225    1   42196000004 Soir 
9   002641   -        263Véh          000077     000889    1   42196000004 Soir 
10  000382   +        263Véh          000077     002095    1   42196000006 Soir 
11  002641   +        287Véh          000087     000889    1   42196000019 Soir 
12  000382   -        263Véh          000077     006168    1   42196000006 Soir 
13  002641   -        287Véh          000087     007225    1   42196000019 Soir 
14  001611   +        287Véh          000087     004236   -1   42196000021 Soir 
15  002785   +        263Véh          000077     007482    1   42196000007 Soir 
16  002372   +        287Véh          000087     007072    1   42196000022 Soir 
17  002785   -        263Véh          000077     007483    1   42196000007 Soir 
18  000466   +        287Véh          000087     004900    1   42196000023 Soir
19  000382   +        263Véh          000077     006168    1   42196000008 Soir
```

For each `Usager`, depending on `Sens` and `Periods`, they can have more than one related address. I want to know for all the `Usager`, how many `address` do they have and the frequency of each address.
I used `frames.set_index(['NoUsager','NoAdresse'])` to make it looks like:

---

**EDIT**

[image: New pic]

I don't want all the other columns but only a new one with the result of frequency. In which way I can do it? Can I use `pivot()` to do it?

Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns which will be `indexes` (`NoUsager`,`Sens`,`Periods`) in output df. Then need add column (`NoAdresse`)  as last item in list in `groupby`, which is converted by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to columns in output. And you need aggregate by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html).

```
df = df.groupby(['NoUsager','Sens','Periods', 'NoAdresse']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
```

```
NoAdresse              79    456   889   2095  2932  4236  4900  6168  6470  \
NoUsager Sens Periods                                                         
1        +    Matin       1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
         -    Matin       1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
314      +    Matin       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1   
         -    Matin       0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
382      +    Soir        0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0   
         -    Soir        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0   
466      +    Matin       0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0   
              Soir        0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0   
         -    Matin       0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0   
1611     +    Soir        0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0   
2372     +    Matin       0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0   
              Soir        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
         -    Matin       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
2641     +    Soir        0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0   
         -    Soir        0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0   
2785     +    Soir        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
         -    Soir        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   

NoAdresse              7072  7225  7482  7483  
NoUsager Sens Periods                          
1        +    Matin       0     0     0     0  
         -    Matin       0     0     0     0  
314      +    Matin       0     0     0     0  
         -    Matin       0     0     0     0  
382      +    Soir        0     0     0     0  
         -    Soir        0     0     0     0  
466      +    Matin       0     0     0     0  
              Soir        0     0     0     0  
         -    Matin       0     0     0     0  
1611     +    Soir        0     0     0     0  
2372     +    Matin       0     0     0     0  
              Soir        1     0     0     0  
         -    Matin       1     0     0     0  
2641     +    Soir        0     1     0     0  
         -    Soir        0     1     0     0  
2785     +    Soir        0     0     1     0  
         -    Soir        0     0     0     1
```

If need reset index:

```
df = df.groupby(['NoUsager','Sens','Periods', 'NoAdresse'])
       .size()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print (df)
    NoUsager Sens Periods  79  456  889  2095  2932  4236  4900  6168  6470  \
0          1    +   Matin   1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
1          1    -   Matin   1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
2        314    +   Matin   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1   
3        314    -   Matin   0    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
4        382    +    Soir   0    0    0     1     0     0     0     1     0   
5        382    -    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     1     0   
6        466    +   Matin   0    0    0     0     1     0     0     0     0   
7        466    +    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0   
8        466    -   Matin   0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0   
9       1611    +    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0     0   
10      2372    +   Matin   0    0    0     0     1     0     0     0     0   
11      2372    +    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
12      2372    -   Matin   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
13      2641    +    Soir   0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0   
14      2641    -    Soir   0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0   
15      2785    +    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
16      2785    -    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   

    7072  7225  7482  7483  
0      0     0     0     0  
1      0     0     0     0  
2      0     0     0     0  
3      0     0     0     0  
4      0     0     0     0  
5      0     0     0     0  
6      0     0     0     0  
7      0     0     0     0  
8      0     0     0     0  
9      0     0     0     0  
10     0     0     0     0  
11     1     0     0     0  
12     1     0     0     0  
13     0     1     0     0  
14     0     1     0     0  
15     0     0     1     0  
16     0     0     0     1
```

---

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab([df.NoUsager,df.Sens,df.Periods], df.NoAdresse)
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print (df)
    NoUsager Sens Periods  79  456  889  2095  2932  4236  4900  6168  6470  \
0          1    +   Matin   1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
1          1    -   Matin   1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
2        314    +   Matin   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1   
3        314    -   Matin   0    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
4        382    +    Soir   0    0    0     1     0     0     0     1     0   
5        382    -    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     1     0   
6        466    +   Matin   0    0    0     0     1     0     0     0     0   
7        466    +    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0   
8        466    -   Matin   0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0   
9       1611    +    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0     0   
10      2372    +   Matin   0    0    0     0     1     0     0     0     0   
11      2372    +    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
12      2372    -   Matin   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
13      2641    +    Soir   0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0   
14      2641    -    Soir   0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0   
15      2785    +    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
16      2785    -    Soir   0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0   

    7072  7225  7482  7483  
0      0     0     0     0  
1      0     0     0     0  
2      0     0     0     0  
3      0     0     0     0  
4      0     0     0     0  
5      0     0     0     0  
6      0     0     0     0  
7      0     0     0     0  
8      0     0     0     0  
9      0     0     0     0  
10     0     0     0     0  
11     1     0     0     0  
12     1     0     0     0  
13     0     1     0     0  
14     0     1     0     0  
15     0     0     1     0  
16     0     0     0     1
```

EDIT by comment:

I think you need only aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['NoUsager','NoAdresse']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df)
    NoUsager  NoAdresse  Count
0          1         79      2
1        314        456      1
2        314       6470      1
3        382       2095      1
4        382       6168      2
5        466       2932      1
6        466       4900      2
7       1611       4236      1
8       2372       2932      1
9       2372       7072      2
10      2641        889      2
11      2641       7225      2
12      2785       7482      1
13      2785       7483      1
```

If need set indexes, you can use another solution - [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) `Series` name and then call [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['NoUsager','NoAdresse']).size().rename('Count').to_frame()
                    Count
NoUsager NoAdresse       
1        79             2
314      456            1
         6470           1
382      2095           1
         6168           2
466      2932           1
         4900           2
1611     4236           1
2372     2932           1
         7072           2
2641     889            2
         7225           2
2785     7482           1
         7483           1
```

Or add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['NoUsager','NoAdresse'])
       .size()
       .reset_index(name='Count')
       .set_index(['NoUsager','NoAdresse'])
print (df)
                    Count
NoUsager NoAdresse       
1        79             2
314      456            1
         6470           1
382      2095           1
         6168           2
466      2932           1
         4900           2
1611     4236           1
2372     2932           1
         7072           2
2641     889            2
         7225           2
2785     7482           1
         7483           1
```

Comment: Might be useful to be aware of some context here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348858/python-pandas-calculation-bewteen-rows-based-on-certain-values-in-columns-fro/39350546#39350546

Comment: @Ninja Puppy♦ - Do you think `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` ? If use `aggfunc` or `crosstab`, there is no problem.

Comment: Not necessarily - just a lot of effort went to get the OP to a point where he got what he wanted (or hope he did) - he's a great guy - don't get me wrong - just not 100% sure what he's after now is exactly what he actually needs...

Comment: @NinjaPuppy - thank you, I am waiting for feedback of OP. ;)

Comment: @jezrael I lost my connection... it's what I want, but is it possible to make it in just one column like the picture I updated?

Comment: @NinjaPuppy it's just I'm doing data analysis with a list of questions and a large amount of data. When I'm not capable to answer questions, I post partial of my intermediate analysis and ask for help. So sometimes the questions seem confusing but I've tried to well explain them... btw, it's a she~

Comment: @jezrael 'cos I still have visualization part to do

Comment: @ch36r5s my apologies - no offence intended. Looks like a project I worked on about allocating car parking spaces coupled with a camera recognising number plates and interfacing with barriers... so it peaked my interested...

Comment: @jezrael yep, that's what I want. btw, I added `set_index(['NoUsager','NoAdresse'])` at the end and the result looks like exactly the same as the pic.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you need set index this way! Nice day!

Comment: @NinjaPuppy none taken. My project is about finding time indicator regularity in a Dial-A-Ride problem. I started it as a logistic/supply chain job but it turned to a programming one...

Comment: I add another solution, `reset_index` and `set_index` is not necessary.

Comment: @jezrael is it possible to drop all the rows with only one `NoAdresse` corresponded to the `NoUsager`? I'm confused 'cos I don't know these with multiple `addresses` count as a row or depending on how many addresses they have?

Comment: Sure, call `df = df[df.Count > 1]` after `groupby`.